# Textbox 100% larger than column size it's within

Tags: html, css

Now the problem I'm seeing, table just grows and scrinks based on window size and data within, except for this one input box.  It wants to be larger than the column itself.   The column has no size set limit and the input has a 100% width, but for some reason it wants to be 110% width, so it seems.  100% has always been based on the outside, so padding and borders should only be taken based on specific px when set.  Can someone tell me why and what I have to do to fix it?

I know for you table haters, you want to start telling me how to code this differently, but I like them and they still work better than a CSS display: table, table-row, table-cell.

```
.inputWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
.textInput {
    border: 5px solid white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 5px;
    background: hsl(120, 100%, 80%);
}
```

[image: Snapshot of problem]

Comment: Remove the padding

Comment: Makes it smaller, but still over the the size of the column.   I want them to have padding and borders.   Doesn't make sense to remove those just so it fits..

Comment: This is not enough information to solve the issue, as style can come from anywhere in the stylesheet. Start by viewing the box model on the item to see where that extra space may be coming from. It is most probably the padding, so you will need to offset it by changing the width to `calc(100% - 10px);` to remove 5px of padding on both sides. You will also probably need to subtract the width of the border (times two - for each side) to make it fit properly.

Comment: @AlgoRythm thanks, but I should see that through Dev Tools.   I see 100%, nothing else is changing that.   I don't have anything in the style sheet that would ever be over 100%.   Event when I remove the padding and the border, it's still 2px over the column size.   The column is a colspan: 2.   So I'm not sure if something there is starting to not work and causing some issues..  I know it's no longer supported by w3c..

Comment: BTW, they calc() works, but feel it's a band-aid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a box sizing issue. I would try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the input. This takes in account padding and border when having `width: 100%;`

Comment: Perfection..   I didn't know about that style..   Thank you.